# C++0x Function delete - Delete all but certain types

Tags: c++11, c-strings, delete-operator, unicode-string

In C++0x, I can do something like this:

```
double f(double x) { return x; }
template<class T>
  T f(T x) = delete;
```

To prevent `f()` from being called on any other type than `double`.

What I'm trying to do is similar, however, not quite the same.

I have a function that operates on pointer arrays.  For example:

```
template<class T>
  T* some_string_function(T* x);
```

I want to be able to make T work for char, char16_t, and char32_t, but not any other type.  I was thinking that C++0x's `delete` would be a good way to accomplish this.  Basically, I want to be able to prevent this function from working with any type that isn't one of the three Unicode `char` types, but I still want to have the benefits of function templates, which allow me to generalise types and avoid repeating code.

What would be the best way to solve this problem?  Is it possible?

Comment: It would have been good if you could `= delete` the function template, and then write non-deleted specialization. But from what I can see from the FDIS, this is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `boost::enable_if`, along with type traits.

```
template<class T>
T* some_string_function(T* x, boost::enable_if<is_char_type<T>);
```

(assuming `is_char_type` is a type trait you define, which evaluates to true for the desired types, and false for all others)

Comment: You don't need boost for this in C++0x, enable_if is part of the standard now.

Comment: Ah true. For some reason I was under the impression that `enable_if` had been left out of C++0x

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using type_traits:

```
template<typename T>
typename enable_if<is_same<char, T>::value || is_same<char16_t, T>::value || is_same<char32_t, T>::value, T*>::type some_string_function(T *x)
{
    return x;
}
```

Though you'd have to specifically specify const as well if you want to allow that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do it is using a combination of static_assert and is_same (Both C++0x features). This also allows for a more friendly error message when you make an invalid call to the function.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T> T* f(T*)
{
    static_assert
    (is_same<T, char>::value
     || is_same<T, char16_t>::value
     || is_same<T, char32_t>::value,
     "Invalid Type, only char pointers allowed");
}

int main()
{
    cout<<*f(new char('c'));//Compiles
    cout<<*f(new int(3));//Error
}
```